# Different results when running code in parallel and sequentially

Tags: c++, openmp

When I run the code, I get different results. I want to simultaneously change different cells of the vector in different threads. The error occurs when there are more threads than cells (Yes, I know that it is not optimal to parallelize in such cases, but I want to understand why the result is different).

it doesn't work

```
w[i] -= speed * derivative[i];
```

it works

```
w[i] = w[i] - speed * derivative[i];
```

all code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <omp.h>
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

class neuron
{
public:
neuron() //constructor with starting filling for example
{
    w.resize(3);
    w[0] = 0.7700484068199707;
    w[1] = 0.3427844318371112;
    w[2] = 0.6822299620512033;
    derivative.resize(3);
    derivative[0] = 0.232342234223;
    derivative[1] = 0.23232232234223;
    derivative[2] = 0.23234334231113;
}

void correction_of_scales(const double& speed)
{
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8) //threads more than cells
    for (size_t i = 0; i < w.size(); ++i)
    {
#pragma omp atomic
        w[i] -= speed * derivative[i]; //here is here is happening what the magic
       //w[i] = w[i] - speed * derivative[i]; - and here it works without errors
    }
}

vector <double> derivative;
vector <double> w; 
};

int main(void)
{
neuron nn;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) //a hundred times in a row change the vector
    nn.correction_of_scales(0.01);

for (int i = 0; i < nn.w.size(); i++)
    cout << scientific << setprecision(15) << nn.w[i] << endl;

system("pause");
}
```

This is what appears when you run it sequentially

```
5.377061725969665e-01  
1.104621094948808e-01  
4.498866197400767e-01
```

But what occurs when you run parallel

```
-6.24004998518318e-01  
1.104621094948808e-01  
4.498866197400767e-01
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the pragma stuff, is it  joining the threads before ending the function. It seems that it wont

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Results are completely identical with both codes and with or without parallelization on linux. Maybe a  problem with your compiler?

Comment: @AlainMerigot - my compiler is Visual Studio.I'll try on Linux.

Comment: @AlainMerigot - yes, on Linux its work

Answer (score -1):

It was an exception from Visual Studio 
[developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/608908/different-results-when-running-code-in-parallel-an.html)